# Return an ordered JSONB nested hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, hash, jsonb

I've a nested JSONB hash that I require to display in date order.

The hash is stored like so:

```
hash = 
{"residential_la"=>
  {"current"=>{"periods"=>{"1/2023"=>"0", "2/2023"=>"0", "3/2023"=>"0", "4/2023"=>"0", "5/2023"=>"0", "6/2023"=>"0", "7/2023"=>"0", "8/2023"=>"0", "9/2023"=>"0", "10/2022"=>"0", "11/2022"=>"0", "12/2022"=>"0"}},
   "original"=>{"periods"=>{"1/2023"=>"901", "2/2023"=>"1315", "3/2023"=>"4377", "4/2023"=>"1815", "5/2023"=>"1835", "6/2023"=>"896", "7/2023"=>"1996", "8/2023"=>"4219", "9/2023"=>"3369", "10/2022"=>"3335", "11/2022"=>"4198", "12/2022"=>"3127"}},
   "NominalCode"=>"500"},
 "residential_private"=>
  {"current"=>{"periods"=>{"1/2023"=>"0", "2/2023"=>"0", "3/2023"=>"0", "4/2023"=>"0", "5/2023"=>"0", "6/2023"=>"0", "7/2023"=>"0", "8/2023"=>"0", "9/2023"=>"0", "10/2022"=>"0", "11/2022"=>"0", "12/2022"=>"0"}},
   "original"=>{"periods"=>{"1/2023"=>"4389", "2/2023"=>"1265", "3/2023"=>"4496", "4/2023"=>"980", "5/2023"=>"1617", "6/2023"=>"1396", "7/2023"=>"4839", "8/2023"=>"4248", "9/2023"=>"1770", "10/2022"=>"3513", "11/2022"=>"1294", "12/2022"=>"4240"}},
   "NominalCode"=>"520"}}
```

As you can see, being JSONB it's storing it in length order. I need to sort this when calling to display in the correct way.

I know for sure I can sort the `periods` nested hash with the following:

```
{ periods: periods_hash[:periods].sort_by { |k, _v| Date.strptime(k, "%d/%Y") }.to_h }
```

This creates a new hash of `periods` and sorts it, correcty.

My problem is getting to this nested hash and returning the full hash with no changes but the order of those periods.

My current efforts produced this:

```
def order_data
    data.each do |_k, v|
      v.each do |sk, sv|
        next if sk.include? "NominalCode"

        sv.each do |x, _y|
         { periods: x[:periods].sort_by { |k, _v| Date.strptime(k, "%d/%Y") }.to_h }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

The above isn't working and gives me `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`, I'm assuiming as I'm `.each`'ing there's a problem with enummerable and the symbols of the hash.

What I'm expecting in return is:

```
{"residential_la"=>
  {"current"=>{"periods"=>{"10/2022"=>"0", "11/2022"=>"0", "12/2022"=>"0", "1/2023"=>"0", "2/2023"=>"0", "3/2023"=>"0", "4/2023"=>"0", "5/2023"=>"0", "6/2023"=>"0", "7/2022"=>"0", "8/2022"=>"0", "9/2022"=>"0"}},
   "original"=>{"periods"=>{"10/2022"=>"0", "11/2022"=>"0", "12/2022"=>"0", "1/2023"=>"0", "2/2023"=>"0", "3/2023"=>"0", "4/2023"=>"0", "5/2023"=>"0", "6/2023"=>"0", "7/2022"=>"0", "8/2022"=>"0", "9/2022"=>"0"}},
   "NominalCode"=>"500"},
"residential_private"=>
  {"current"=>{"periods"=>{"10/2022"=>"0", "11/2022"=>"0", "12/2022"=>"0", "1/2023"=>"0", "2/2023"=>"0", "3/2023"=>"0", "4/2023"=>"0", "5/2023"=>"0", "6/2023"=>"0", "7/2022"=>"0", "8/2022"=>"0", "9/2022"=>"0"}},
   "original"=>{"periods"=>{"10/2022"=>"0", "11/2022"=>"0", "12/2022"=>"0", "1/2023"=>"0", "2/2023"=>"0", "3/2023"=>"0", "4/2023"=>"0", "5/2023"=>"0", "6/2023"=>"0", "7/2022"=>"0", "8/2022"=>"0", "9/2022"=>"0"}},
   "NominalCode"=>"500"}
```

I'm unsure whether I should be mapping to create a new hash, or just iterating through with each to only modify the sub hash, ultimately there's a lack of understanding on my part, any help and guidance is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following task definition:

- we need to sort any hash under key `periods`...
- regardless of its (`periods`) depth
- and keep everything else intact

one could go with the simple recursive algorithm (let's name it `deep_sort_periods`):

1. Start with a new hash (n)
2. Check the next key/value (k/v) of the existing hash
3. If the `v` is not a hash leave it as is (set `n[k] = v`)
4. If the `v` is a hash and `k` is `periods` - sort the value (`n[k] = <your sorting logic>`)
5. Otherwise (`v` is a hash but `k` is smth. different, not `periods`) - repeat 1-4 for the nested hash and assign the result to `n[k]` (`n[k] = deep_sort_periods(v)`)

The implementation can literally follow the description, kinda:

```
def deep_sort_periods(hash)
  hash.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), new_hash|
    if !v.is_a?(Hash)
      new_hash[k] = v
    elsif k == "periods"
      new_hash[k] = v.sort_by { |date, _| Date.strptime(date, "%d/%Y") }.to_h
    else
      new_hash[k] = deep_sort_periods(v)
    end
  end
end
```

and then

```
pry(main)> deep_sort_periods(hash)
=> {"residential_la"=>
  {"current"=>{"periods"=>{"7/2022"=>"0", "8/2022"=>"0", "9/2022"=>"0", "10/2022"=>"0", "11/2022"=>"0", "12/2022"=>"0", "1/2023"=>"0", "2/2023"=>"0", "3/2023"=>"0", "4/2023"=>"0", "5/2023"=>"0", "6/2023"=>"0"}},
   "original"=>{"periods"=>{"7/2022"=>"0", "8/2022"=>"0", "9/2022"=>"0", "10/2022"=>"0", "11/2022"=>"0", "12/2022"=>"0", "1/2023"=>"0", "2/2023"=>"0", "3/2023"=>"0", "4/2023"=>"0", "5/2023"=>"0", "6/2023"=>"0"}},
   "NominalCode"=>"500"},
 "residential_private"=>
  {"current"=>{"periods"=>{"7/2022"=>"0", "8/2022"=>"0", "9/2022"=>"0", "10/2022"=>"0", "11/2022"=>"0", "12/2022"=>"0", "1/2023"=>"0", "2/2023"=>"0", "3/2023"=>"0", "4/2023"=>"0", "5/2023"=>"0", "6/2023"=>"0"}},
   "original"=>{"periods"=>{"7/2022"=>"0", "8/2022"=>"0", "9/2022"=>"0", "10/2022"=>"0", "11/2022"=>"0", "12/2022"=>"0", "1/2023"=>"0", "2/2023"=>"0", "3/2023"=>"0", "4/2023"=>"0", "5/2023"=>"0", "6/2023"=>"0"}},
   "NominalCode"=>"500"}}
```

Disclaimer: if there are more restrictions for the task definition - for example, `periods` are not arbitrarily nested but rather sit at some fixed depth - the task most probably can be solved in a more concise and performant way with no recursion at all...

Comment: Hi there, this is a great answer and awesome explanation! To answer your question `periods` will always remain at that depth.

What I was intending was to call the singular record within the controller action to sort the hash, then use that record through view etc.. as normal.